# Which fingering system is easier on the Roland AE-01, trumpet or recorder?

Tags: learning, fingering, trumpet, recorder, ewi

1. The Roland AE-01 (digital wind instrument) has fingering for recorder and trumpet. There is no need to develop blowing technique.
2. I played the trumpet years ago so I can recall some of it.
3. In terms of learning at a very basic level, is there more available for either trumpet or recorder?
4. Will learning fingering for recorder limit my selection of music? For example, to music played by Chris Botti or The Moody Blues. I'm not interested in playing what most might expect from recorder.
5. As we get older unfortunately it gets more difficult to learn or remember things — that's the basis for the question.

Comment: To me this is subjective. In some ways trumpet fingering is much easier because you only need to understand seven positions on the trumpet. Both instruments require using "overblowing" to access the full range. Another advantage of the trumpet is valves have only two positions, while recorder hole may be half covered. Some fingering patterns on recorder are unintuitive. Trumpet valves do the same things in all registers. On the other hand, some may find recording fingering makes more sense to them, as PiedPiper's answer suggests. It's a matter of taste.

Comment: It took me a while to understand you're not asking whether an actual trumpet or recorder is easier to play. You're asking about the specific options on the Roland AE-01. I've edited your title to clarify. I still think the question is subjective. If one fingering were universally better than the other in some way, they wouldn't offer multiple fingering options. The options exist because people's brains work differently.

Comment: @ToddWilcox The problem with this instrument is the fingerings are not really recorder or trumpet fingerings. The 'trumpet' fingerings require eight fingers, and the 'recorder' fingerings don't use cross-fingerings or half-holes. The 'recorder' is much closer to  a saxophone.

Answer (score 4):

Most people, possibly even trumpet players, would find the simplified 'recorder' fingerings more logical. Put down all your fingers, take them off one by one and you're already playing a C-major scale. For sharps and flats just add one of the two LH 4th finger keys.
The 'trumpet' fingerings are less logical: the right hand plays the standard trumpet fingerings, but you have to simulate changing harmonics with different combinations of left-hand keys.

Whichever fingering system you choose you'll be able to play any kind of music. You're not restricted to music written for trumpet or recorder.